how to get time zone America/Montreal using std::chrono + MSVC 2022 + Windows 11
using MSVC 2022 with windows 11 when I try with std::chrono to get some time zone information it fails with an exception on certain time zone that I extracted from:
std::chrono::get_tzdb().zones

The what() function just return unknown error!
I've simplify the code just to show the problem.
What I would like to do is to us an if statement to check if the time zone is ok to be used!
for now I must «sprinkle» my code with try/catch
here is the failing code:
#include <chrono>

int main(int, char**)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto z = std::chrono::get_tzdb().locate_zone("America/Montreal");
    if (z != nullptr)   // useless
    {
        auto QuebecDay = 2023y / 6 / 24;
        auto info = z->get_info(std::chrono::sys_days(QuebecDay));
    }
    return 0;
}

I have the same problem with many time zones I enumerate from the tzdb.
My icu.dll is dated: 14 nov 2023, so quite recent
I am using windows 11 professional  23H2

Did you try America/Toronto?

Just a small precision upon the comment from @ChristianStieber in case you wonder how his suggestion could possibly work with it but not with your attempt: America/Montreal redirects to America/Toronto in the IANA time zone database (see here, column Notes). I am unable to tell if the DLL hides the fact that one simply links to the other and treats them in an identical way; above is a reason to think it might not be the case.

America/Montreal was provided by tzdb::zones, So I thought the locate_zone would work.
I cannot use America/Toronto, as I have no way (standard) to map it  to Amrica/Montreal.
I used America/Montreal as an example, but the problem was found with America/Anchorage, which prompted me for more investigations.

@atmo yes I know that America/Montreal redirect to America/Toronto, but I am using windows & MSVC 2022, and for now, no standard way of discovering that.

A simple wrapper around std::chrono::locate_zone should give you the error checking style you prefer:
#include <chrono>
#include <string_view>

auto
my_locate_zone(std::string_view tz)
{
    try
    {
        return std::chrono::locate_zone(tz);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return static_cast<std::chrono::time_zone const*>(nullptr);
    }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto z = my_locate_zone("America/Montreal");
    if (z != nullptr)
    {
        auto QuebecDay = 2023y / 6 / 24;
        auto info = z->get_info(std::chrono::sys_days(QuebecDay));
    }
    return 0;
}

"America/Montreal" is a link to "America/Toronto" located in the "backward" file of the IANA time zone database.  It may be that ICU does not include this part of the database.  If the link was included in the database, std::chrono::locate_zone would find it and return a pointer to the "America/Toronto" time_zone.

Thanks
I did check the tzdb::links and it was not there, but when I enumerate tzdb::zones I get the America/Montreal (and a bunch of others) that throw when I tried to locate it!
this is the solution I have (try/catch). I was just wondering if I was missing something obvious.
I've also checked the link, because under linux this works, so I thought it was something under windows that I did not understand.

If you found America/Montreal via iteration but not via locate_zone, this is probably worth a bug report to MSVC.
